# CentOS libvirt reboot

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

I've noticed the following status message after system update (on SL 6.1 - yum update):

```
# /etc/init.d/libvirtd status
libvirtd dead but pid file exists
```

- one of the updated packages was "libvirt". Is it possible that this caused the issue?
- if I'll restart the "libvirtd" daemon this will also restart all the KVM VMs?

I'm not sure if the "libvirt" service was restarted automatically during the update process (like MySQL does)?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely libvirt exited uncleanly at some point, leaving the PID file behind.

Anyway, libvirt won't restart the VMs that are currently running. However, it will start up the VMs that are marked as "boot automatically" but were shut off.

Comment: Hi, it looks like there is some issue:

# /etc/init.d/libvirtd restart
Stopping libvirtd daemon:                                  [FAILED]
Starting libvirtd daemon:                                  [  OK  ]
# /etc/init.d/libvirtd status
libvirtd dead but pid file exists

Could you please advise how I can investigate further?

Comment: the PID file might have the old PID that is no longer running. So, it cannot kill the old process. therefore, it fails. you can try to stop libvirt, delete the existing PID file, and starting libvirt again, manually.